# Need help adding featured thumbnail to search.php in wordpress twenty-eleven theme

Tags: wordpress

Hi I need help adding my thumbnail to the search results of my search.php page on WordPress as seen below.

I am kind of a newbie and do not want to mess up my code. I have already set up a child theme for this page so have no fear that I would alter the main theme.

Thumbnail support should already be turned on for this theme I just I want to add the thumbnail centered under the page title. Thanks

```
<section id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <header class="page-header">
            <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'twentytwelve' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
        </header>

        <?php twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
            <header class="entry-header">
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h1>
            </header>

            <div class="entry-content">
                <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></p>
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        </article><!-- #post-0 -->

    <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</section><!-- #primary -->
```

Comment: Have you checked out the_post_thumbnail() - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/ ?

Comment: Ok I just checked that out and I understand I have to use something like 'the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );' but do I use it in the search.php or do I add it to "post-thumbnail-template.php"

Comment: Do you want to add the thumbnail / featured image of the first result under the page header? Since search isn't a page, but a built-in template, you'll need to pick where the thumbnail is coming from.  Are the thumbnails for each individual post showing up in the results?